# Make svg icon color on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to svg icons and I just need to change the color of this icon on hover.

This is what I have so far: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/e1491y39/3/)

```
.search-social :hover .search-icon {
    fill: #72dcff;
}
```

It's just working from the fiddle as you can see since  I applied`.search-social` on both of them.

But is this solution clean or do you suggest a better solution?

Comment: You change the fill on hover, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: I was thinking that also the way I applied the css style, using the class of the div "search-social" then ":hover" then the class of the svg "search-icon" could be done easier. Let me know if there could be any improvement.

Comment: If this is working (which it is) then this question is off-topic for SO. Perhaps CodeReview would be a better fit but check their guidelines first.

Comment: better to simplify your svg (using AI compound path) and then use selector .search-social:hover svg > * {}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e1491y39/4/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/e1491y39/4/

I think it's because you've got strokes and fills and separate pieces. So if you make it a single path, you could just use that single path. Otherwise, you could use a hover on the SVG itself. (See jsFiddle.)

```
.
```